# Cannot create a file or Document with Nautilus or Thunar in Home Directory

Tags: nautilus

Hey Trying to diagnose an issue where when using a File Manager(Thundar and Nautilus) in my Home directory I cannot create a file or Directory.  I can create files and directories from the Terminal as my user, but when I open the File Manager the option to create files and Directories is greyed out.

Comment: What's the output of `touch ~/Desktop/temp.txt`?

Comment: It creates the files no errors.

Comment: Just as a test (I'm not sure why this is happening to you) can you go up a directory level in say Thunar, right click on the /home/user account and see if write permissions are enabled in there? I'm assuming you mean *your* home directory as in /home/user and not the /home directory.

Comment: So I can create a directory or file in /home/<User Account>.   Cannot seem to do it in Documents.  I also can create directory or account in Downloads and other directories under /home/<User Account>

Comment: Hmm... I'd check permissions and ownership of the files, as that's all I can think of. (Sorry for the delay, I've been otherwise engaged.)